# How to edit grid box height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is it possible to make the total lengh of boxes 3-15 shorter than the length of box 2? I want them to be tabs that don't span along the body text (box 2) but instead are about 1/5 as long as box 2.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-auto-rows:minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}
.wrapper > div {
background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ddd;
}
.box1 {
  grid-row:1/3;
}
.box2 {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row:1/16;
}
.jsdoc {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box1">
  <h1 class="jsdoc">JS documentation</h1>
     </div>
  <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box4">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box5">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box6">Box 6</div>
  <div class="box7">Box 7</div>
  <div class="box8">Box 8</div>
  <div class="box9">Box 9</div>
  <div class="box10">Box 10</div>
  <div class="box11">Box 11</div>
  <div class="box12">Box 12</div>
  <div class="box13">Box 13</div>
  <div class="box14">Box 14</div>
  <div class="box15">Box 15</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating all the boxes side by side, you should create 3 boxes first. `.box1` for heading, `.box2` for body and another box for tab items and put all the box inside the new box. Then you can style to grow the new box as you want. May be `grid-row:3/6;`.

Check my approach:

```css
 .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
        grid-auto-rows:minmax(100px, auto);
        grid-gap: 1em;
    }
    .wrapper > div, .wrapper > div.tabs > div{
        background: #eee;
        padding: 1em;
    }
    .wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #ddd;
    }
    .box1 {
        grid-row:1/3;
        /* Vertically Center The Heading */
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .box2 {
        grid-row:1/16;
    }
    .wrapper > div.tabs {
        grid-row:3/6;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-gap: 1em;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .jsdoc {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box1">
            <h1 class="jsdoc">JS documentation</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
            <div class="box4">Box 4</div>
            <div class="box5">Box 5</div>
            <div class="box6">Box 6</div>
            <div class="box7">Box 7</div>
            <div class="box8">Box 8</div>
            <div class="box9">Box 9</div>
            <div class="box10">Box 10</div>
            <div class="box11">Box 11</div>
            <div class="box12">Box 12</div>
            <div class="box13">Box 13</div>
            <div class="box14">Box 14</div>
            <div class="box15">Box 15</div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

Hope this approach will help you to create that you are trying to create.